# Updating rows in order with SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with 4 columns. The first column is unique for each row, but it's a string (URL format).
I want to update my table, but instead of using "WHERE", I want to update the rows in order.
The first query will update the first row, the second query updates the second row and so on.

What's the SQL code for that? I'm using Sqlite.

Edit: My table schema

```
CREATE table (
url varchar(150),
views int(5),
clicks int(5)
)
```

Edit2: What I'm doing right now is a loop of SQL queries

update table set views = 5, click = 10 where url = "http://someurl.com";

There is around 4 million records in the database. It's taking around 16 seconds in my server to make the update. Since the loop update the row in order, so the first query update the first row; I'm thinking if updating the rows in order could be faster than using the WHERE clause which needs to browse 4 million rows.

Comment: You seriously need to post a DDL.  But it appears that you are not approaching a solution the right way.

Comment: I added it. It's pretty simple.

Comment: More details please.  In order of what? Which column?  What is the nature of a process that wants to go row by row like that? What are you trying to actually do or why?

Comment: You need to explain some more what you are trying to achieve. For instance show and example of the contents of the table before and after the update(s)..

Comment: In standard SQL, rows don't *have* an order within a table - they are to be treated, for all intents and purposes, as a set.

Comment: 16 seconds is a lot of time to spend on single update. Is there a primary key or unique index on _url_?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović No, there isn't a primary key or a unique index. What the time should be on a 512MB VPS server. I'm using files right now, it takes 0.05sec so I'll probably stick with them.

Comment: I was thinking that if url is not indexed it takes a full table scan to find exact record for "http://someurl.com" - adding an index would speed things up. Other that that, I don't understand what are you trying to do, so if you could post some details about your intent that would satisfy my curiousity...

Comment: Well, I have a very large tables with URLs and I need to update the views and clicks fields for each URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want without using WHERE as this is the *only* way to select rows from a table for reading, updating or deleting. So you will want to use:

```
UPDATE table SET url = ... WHERE url = '<whatever>'
```

**HOWEVER**... SqlLite has an extra feature - the [autogenerated column, ROWID](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid). You can use this column in queries. You don't see this data by default, so if you want the data within it you need to explicitly request it, e.g:

```
SELECT ROWID, * FROM table
```

What this means is that you may be able to do what you want referencing this column directly:

```
UPDATE table SET url = ... WHERE ROWID = 1
```

you still need to use the `WHERE` clause, but this allows you to access the rows in insert order without doing anything else.

**CAVEAT**
ROWID effectively stores the `INSERT` order of the rows. If you delete rows from the table, the ROWIDs for remaining rows will ***NOT*** change - hence it is possible to have gaps in the ROWID sequence. This is by design and there is no workaround short of re-creating the table and re-populating the data.

**PORTABILITY**
Note that this only applies to SQLite - you may not be able to do the same thing with other SQL engines should you ever need to port this. It would be MUCH better to add an EXPLICIT auto-number column (aka an `IDENTITY` field) that you can use and manage.

Comment: Thanks for the ROWID solution, what I was looking for. I hope it has some performance boosts :)